# Duplicate keys in Dictionary<string,EventHandler>

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, dictionary

I have

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, EventHandler> CacheHandlers = new Dictionary<string, EventHandler>();
```

and I have duplicate keys in this dictionary:

debugger screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuXI7.png

How does it happen?

Is it a bug in the .net framework or could it be an artifact of concurent usage?

Comment: Why do you use a run-time class instead of `CacheHandlers.Keys` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) states that Dictionarys might not be thread safe.

If you are concurrently reading from the Dictionary, then it *might* be safe so long as you lock the Dictionary when you add new key/value pairs.